# Installing X.org (opensource) Ubuntu driver in the terminal

Tags: ati, xorg, fglrx, gpu-driver, official-repositories

Software Center messed up my proprietary driver installation and I must revert to the original driver (the one you can find in "Additional Drivers" tab under software sources.

[image]

However Software Center corrupted my video driver and Software Sources does not allow me to revert or change anything. Completely removing the proprietary driver leaves me with a corrupted x.org and does not work. Where can I download an exact copy of the "X.org AMD display wrapper" and install it because right now I have no GUI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have access to the text console. If not, login and use CTRL + ALT + F2 to sign in with no graphics after you boot up.

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
```

This will install the driver you are talking about.

Reboot for the changes to take effect.

To first remove fglrx "proprietary-drivers" you could run this before the installation.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx fglrx-amdcccle fglrx-amdcccle-updates fglrx-updates fglrx-updates-dev fglrx-dev
```

Comment: Ok so at first i purged fglrx along with xorg and then installed xorg again and it still gives me thr system problem detected error. How can i launch a terminal into gui from teletype because gui isnt frozen yet ctrl-alt-T doesnt work

Comment: I don't know about teletype, however, you can either boot recovery mode from grub and select to drop into a root shell or you can use CTRL + ALT + F2 after you boot even if x does not start and the TTY2 text shell has all the capabilities as CTRL + ALT + T does.

Answer (score 0):

you can install the ati radeon driver like this

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo amdconfig --initial && sudo shutdown -r
```

after the restart

Alt+F2

> "gksu amdcccle"

Comment: see now, amdconfig and cccle are apps that only work with fglrx (proprietary) driver whcih is not compatible with the fresh version of x.org on 14.04. im asking for the exact driver you see at the top in the picture, know what im talking about?

Comment: theres 2 drivers, xorg which is opensource and fglrx which is proprietary, im looking for the official package to the opensource which is published by ubuntu

Comment: @NickBailuc you can run the software & sources as admin '$ sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4' then edit what you want

Comment: it didnt install (update) anything because t thinks i have a locked proprietary driver placed in my system. i need to manually install the driver rather than using apt-get or update manager

Comment: those drivers are private codes you can only install them like this

Comment: No theyre not, xorg is fully opensource

Comment: Fglrx is proprietary, not xorg